# Testimonies of "Not to turn over a slave who seeks refuge"

Tags: mitzvah, slave-serve-eved-avadim

[Deuteronomy.23.16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.23.16?lang=en&with=Rashi&lang2=en) prescribes not to turn over a slave to his master. There's some Halachic discourse and the MT is very scarce adding that it only applies from abroad to Eretz Israel.

Are there any testimonies, experiences, or stories about this practice? Is anybody mentioned performing this Mitzva?

Comment: I've never turned over a slave to his master.  Does that count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's one case brought in [Gittin 45a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gittin.45a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> The Gemara relates: There was a certain slave who fled from his master from outside of Eretz Yisrael to Eretz Yisrael. His master followed him to Eretz Yisrael and came before Rabbi Ami. Rabbi Ami said to the master: We will write a promissory note for his value for you, and you should write a bill of manumission for him. And if you do not do this, I will remove him from you entirely, since he does not have to return to outside of Eretz Yisrael, based on the statement of Rabbi Aḥai, son of Rabbi Yoshiya.